# Airflow docker debug using Pycharm IDE

Tags: docker, pycharm, airflow

I'm using `Pycharm v 2023.1.1` and an experienced user of this IDE and trying to debug this local `apache/airflow:2.4.3-python3.10` docker image.

- I'm trying to debug like this youtube [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=erVa79aihZE&t=11s)
- Which I've setup as per this [medium link](https://medium.com/@andrewhharmon/apache-airflow-using-pycharm-and-docker-for-remote-debugging-b2d1edf83d9d)

### Here's my setup:

1. I added the remote docker interpreter using docker server
   [image].
2. However I've built my docker image with a local requirements.txt that has e.g. the `great_expectations` package *which doesn't appear* because this interpreter is using the image tag
3. I then try to run an airflow dag via the console after I've started the docker stack which completes with error

### Try to debug

1. This is my run configuration and using the same interpreter. **Parameters:** `tasks test great_expectations ge_data_context_root_dir_with_checkpoint_name_pass "2023-05-13"`
   [image: run_config]
2. However it can't find the dag[image]
3. But the same parameters when run on command line does find it and successfully tests it: `docker exec -it local-airflow-airflow-worker-1 /bin/bash -c 'airflow tasks test great_expectations ge_data_context_root_dir_with_checkpoint_name_pass "2023-05-13"'`
4. I changed to instead use `docker compose` interpreter but get a different error [image: docker-compose interpreter][image: another error]

---